# ValueError: num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples=0

Tags: python, deep-learning, path, pytorch, dataset

I have data organized as follows: /dataset/train_or_validation/neg_or_pos_class/images.png
So, inside train or validation I have 2 folders, 1 for negative and 1 for positive.
I have the error of the title `ValueError: num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples=0` because basically I am inside /dataset/train_or_validation, but then I need to access the folders neg or pos. Images are in this format: MCUCXR_0000_1.png for positive images, while MCUCXR_0000_0.png for negative class. I was thinking to extract all the images from the folders, in order to have /dataset/train_or_validation/images.png, but in this case how I can specify which is the class?
Or, how can I iterate through the positive/negative folders?
This is my code:

```
"""Montgomery Shard Descriptor."""

import logging
import os
from typing import List
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
import requests

from openfl.interface.interactive_api.shard_descriptor import ShardDataset
from openfl.interface.interactive_api.shard_descriptor import ShardDescriptor

from torchvision import transforms

# Compose transformations
train_transform = transforms.Compose([
  transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
  transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(),
  transforms.Resize((512, 512)),
  transforms.ToTensor(),
])

test_transform = transforms.Compose([
  transforms.Resize((512, 512)),
  transforms.ToTensor(),
])

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MontgomeryShardDataset(ShardDataset):
    """Montgomery Shard dataset class."""

    def __init__(self, dataset_dir: Path, dataset_type: str,):
        """Initialize MontgomeryDataset."""
        self.data_type = dataset_type
        self.dataset_dir = dataset_dir
        print(self.dataset_dir)
        self.imgs_path = list(dataset_dir.glob('*.png'))
        
    def __getitem__(self, index: int):
        """Return an item by the index."""
        img_path = self.imgs_path[index]
        img = Image.open(img_path)
        return img

    def __len__(self):
        """Return the len of the dataset."""
        return len(self.imgs_path)


class MontgomeryShardDescriptor(ShardDescriptor):
    """Montgomery Shard descriptor class."""

    def __init__(
            self,
            data_folder: str = 'montgomery_data',
            **kwargs
    ):
        """Initialize MontgomeryShardDescriptor."""
        #print("Path at terminal when executing this file")
        print(os.getcwd() + "\n")
        #print(self.common_data_folder)
        self.data_folder = data_folder 
        self.dataset_dir = Path.cwd() / data_folder
        trainset, testset = self.get_data()
        print("IO SONO" + "\n")
        print(self.dataset_dir)
        self.data_by_type = {
            'train': self.dataset_dir / 'TRAIN',
            'val': self.dataset_dir / 'TEST'
        }

    def get_shard_dataset_types(self) -> List[str]:
        """Get available shard dataset types."""
        return list(self.data_by_type)

    def get_dataset(self, dataset_type='train'):
        """Return a shard dataset by type."""
        print("Path at terminal when executing this file")
        print(os.getcwd() + "\n")
        #os.chdir("/home/lmancuso/openfl/openfl-tutorials/interactive_api/OPENLAB/envoy")
        if dataset_type not in self.data_by_type:
            raise Exception(f'Wrong dataset type: {dataset_type}')
        return MontgomeryShardDataset(
            dataset_dir=self.data_by_type[dataset_type],
            dataset_type=dataset_type,
        )

    @property
    def sample_shape(self):
        """Return the sample shape info."""
        return ['3', '512', '512']

    @property
    def target_shape(self):
        """Return the target shape info."""
        return ['3', '512', '512']

    @property
    def dataset_description(self) -> str:
        """Return the dataset description."""
        return (f'Montgomery dataset, shard number')

    def get_data(self):
        root_dir = "montgomery_data"
        #train_set = ImageFolder(os.path.join(root_dir, "TRAIN"), transform=train_transform)
        #test_set = ImageFolder(os.path.join(root_dir, "TEST"), transform=test_transform)
        train_set = os.path.join(root_dir, "TRAIN")
        test_set = os.path.join(root_dir, "TEST")

        print('Montgomery data was loaded!')
        return train_set, test_set
```

I am using the framework for Federated Learning developed by Intel, OpenFL.
As you can see I tried also to use ImageFolder because I think it can be useful in this case.

EDIT with the full traceback:

```
new_state[k] = pt.from_numpy(tensor_dict.pop(k)).to(device)
           ERROR    Collaborator failed with error: num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples=0:                           envoy.py:93
                    Traceback (most recent call last):
                      File "/home/lmancuso/openfl/openfl/component/envoy/envoy.py", line 91, in run
                        self._run_collaborator()
                      File "/home/lmancuso/openfl/openfl/component/envoy/envoy.py", line 164, in _run_collaborator
                        col.run()
                      File "/home/lmancuso/openfl/openfl/component/collaborator/collaborator.py", line 145, in run
                        self.do_task(task, round_number)
                      File "/home/lmancuso/openfl/openfl/component/collaborator/collaborator.py", line 259, in do_task
                        **kwargs)
                      File "/home/lmancuso/openfl/openfl/federated/task/task_runner.py", line 117, in collaborator_adapted_task
                        loader = self.data_loader.get_train_loader()
                      File "/tmp/ipykernel_8572/1777129341.py", line 35, in get_train_loader
                      File "/home/lmancuso/bruno/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 262, in __init__
                        sampler = RandomSampler(dataset, generator=generator)  # type: ignore
                      File "/home/lmancuso/bruno/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py", line 104, in __init__
                        "value, but got num_samples={}".format(self.num_samples))
                    ValueError: num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples=0
           INFO     Send WaitExperiment request                                                                                            director_client.py:80
           INFO     WaitExperiment response has received                                                                                   director_client.py:82
```

Comment: Post the full traceback. It is currently not clear where the error occurs as `num_samples` does not appear in the code you posted.

Comment: I edited the original post. However, I do not know if in this case the full traceback is useful because it contains references to OpenFL

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the dataset is empty. The datapath may be wrong or preprocessing might be causing problems ending up with no object in Dataset object.

Answer (score 2):

Its because our list of images or labels is empty.
Considering the dataset class from above question,

```
self.imgs_path = list(dataset_dir.glob('*.png'))
```

is empty.
and hence

```
def __len__(self):
    """Return the len of the dataset."""
    return len(self.imgs_path)
```

this method return `len = 0`.

So make sure that data is read correctly.
verify it by printing this `len`